# Having some trouble sending data to alerts using React-Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, react-bootstrap

Using React, Next.JS and React-Bootstrap

So, i'm just looking for a way to send data to an Alert react component, that way i can just use one block of code, and repurpose it for all kinds of different alert needs, not just one single paragraph or use case or anything.

Now, to preface, i'm not sure this is something i can natively do within the realm of React and React-Bootstrap, but it just seems like a very React way to do things, and i'm a bit stuck to be completely honest. I'm still learning this whole ecosystem together, so id ask if you could please forgive me if this comes off as amateurish or simple!

Lemme explain how i did it before

So, back in plain HTML and JS, i could simply have

```
<div id="myAlert" class="alert">
            <div class="alert-content">
                <div class="alert-header">
                    <h2>Alert</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="alert-body">
                    <p id="alertMessage"></p>
                    <button id="okBtnAlert" class="alertBtn" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Sitting up at the top of my index.html, and in my main.js i could have

```
function showPopup(newMessage, functionToDo) {
    var OKBtn = document.getElementById("okBtn");
    var CancelBtn = document.getElementById("cancelBtn");
    var pop = document.getElementById("myPopup");

    document.getElementById('popupMessage').innerHTML = newMessage;

    pop.style.display = "block";

    OKBtn.onclick = function() {
        pop.style.display = "none";
        eval(functionToDo);
    }

    CancelBtn.onclick = function() {
        pop.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == pop) {
            pop.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

With this, i could just call the showPopup method anytime i wanted to show my users a popup to inform them of invalid information, or give them a warning about an action they're performing, and be able to use custom inner html information, as well as provide a method to be performed if the user confirms what's going on.

So, here's what i tried to do in React-Bootstrap

First, i created my own component

```
import {Alert} from 'react-bootstrap'

const Alert = (onClose, alertHeading, alertText, alertVariant, methodToExecute) => {
    return (
        <Alert variant={alertVariant} onClose={onClose} dismissible>
            <Alert.Heading>{alertHeading}</Alert.Heading>
            <p>{alertText}</p>   
            <Button variant={alertVariant} onclick={methodToExecute}></Button>
        </Alert>
    )
}

export default Alert
```

Which, i think is the right way to do that. So, there i basically have my HTML and Javascript replaced with more React friendly syntax.

The problem i am running into, is *where* do i implement this at?

The first thing i tried was down in the return for my index.js, just on the main screen where i wanted it to appear at.

So i tried putting this in

```
{show ? <Alert/> : ''}
```

Which works for showing the alert, however i'm at a a bit of a loss on how to dynamically change this.

I had the idea to put `{alerts}` down in my return, and have a list containing alert objects that the page dynamically draws, however, when i did that, my alerts would only display when there is some sort of "page refresh", for some reason they would not dynamically get added when they were added.

So, what do you think? I definitely could just try and implement my own div like that, but i think trying to work it into React with components, and using bootstrap components seems like the best way to go about it. Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: i have further tried to scrap the idea of a "myAlert" class, and instead just put `{alerts.length > 0 ? <Alerts alerts={alerts} /> : ''}` down there, however, this has not yielded great results. I created a helper function, here

```
const pushAlert = (onClosing, alertHeading, alertText, alertVariant, methodToExecute, buttonText) => {
        alerts.push({
            "onClosing": onClosing,
            "alertHeading": alertHeading,
            "alertText": alertText, 
            "alertVariant": alertVariant, 
            "methodToExecute": methodToExecute,
            "buttonText": buttonText
        })
}
```

creating an object that i can then send to the component and pull out of. This kind of works, however, opening and closing still doesen't work, and it isn't dynamic, like, it only shows up with a hard refresh.

Comment: could it have anything to do with the fact that you import `Alert` and then immediately overwrite it in the next line? I'm not an expert in the internals of JS, but that could be part of your problem. Regardless of whether it does work, it's bad practice to overwrite variables with the same name. you could just as easily do `const myAlert = (...)=>{...}; export default myAlert;` without affecting any of your dependencies.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth i was thinking the same thing, i did end up changing it to myAlert and it had no impact on the situation :/